# How to display the content of an ELF file in QTextEdit?

Tags: qt, binary, elf

I need to display all the bytes from and ELF file to a QTextEdit and i did not find any reasonable way to do this. I could print maximum "?ELF??" then nothing. The content of the ELF is read in a char* array (this is a requirement, can't change that) and yes, for sure the content is read.

Comment: I need every byte of the ELF to be displayed too

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that your code looks something like this:

```
char *elf = ReadElfFile();
QString str(elf);  // Constructs a string initialized with the 8-bit string str.
QTextEdit edit(str);
```

The problem is that `QString` constructor will *stop* on first `NUL` character, and the ELF file is *full* of them.

If you want to make a `QString` that contains `NUL`s, do something like this:

```
QString str(QByteArray(elf, length_of_elf));
```

Comment: No, it is not an XY Problem. I want to achieve exactly what i wrote there. And no, my QTextEdit should not dispaly it like 0x7F 0x45 0x4C 0x46. I want it as you see it when you open an ELF with whatever text editor you choose. You are right tho about the QString NUL.

Comment: @Sokolotov I think you _do_ have an XY problem, but updated the answer.

Comment: it is not a XY problem. And what you suggested does not work, it has the same output: stops on the first \0.

Answer (score 0):

This just nearly broke me too, so I'll post my solution to anyone interested.

Let's say I have a `QByteArray data` that is filled like so

```cpp
    data += file.readAll();
```

I'll then invoke an update of the `QTextEdit` where I'll do

```cpp
    QByteArray copy = data;
    QString text = copy.replace((char)0x00, "\\0");
    textEdit.setPlainText(text);
```

This way, all null bytes in the data will be displayed as the printable string `\0`.

Since I want changes of the `textEdit` to be reflected in my `data`, I have to parse this back using

```cpp
    QByteArray hex = textEdit.toPlainText().toUtf8().toHex().toUpper();
    hex.replace("5C30", "00");
    hex.replace("5C00", "5C30"); // oops, was escaped
    data = QByteArray::fromHex(hex);
```

I'm using the hex format because I just could not get the replace to work with null byte characters. The code above first replaces all occurrences of the string `\0` with null bytes in the data. Then it replaces any `\` followed by a null byte back with `\0` - which essentially means `\\0` becomes `\0`.

It's not very elegant, but maybe it helps anyone ending up here to move on in the right direction. If you have improvements, please comment.